# override context menu for image right click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am working on website development i want to disable save image from my website, so i want to disable save image as and view image option please can any one help me.I want to disable specific option.

Comment: You should be aware that there is no way to completely prevent that. Users can always work around JavaScript solutions.

Comment: I tried conextmenu thing but i dont want to disable comp-lete right click i want to disable only save image and view image option

Comment: There is no way to block image saving. The user can simply turn JavaScript off and right-click it. Smarter users will just click the link in the source code to go to the image. This is unfortunately simply something you have no control of.

Comment: okay spokey is their anyway to override context menu options??/

Comment: @Karthik You can create your own, but not override it

Comment: @Spokey can u tell me how can i create??

Comment: I am sure there are many tutorials on the internet that will help you create one. If you find one and have problems with it feel free to create a new question about that on stackoverflow describing the problem and where the code does not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can try displaying your images as a background to `div` elements with CSS like:

```
background-image: url('images/some_image.png');
```

instead of using `img` tags.
This way, the users would not get the usual *save image* option in context menu as one would expect.

Comment: This only works for the Naive users, there is nothing there to stop web developers as it is already mentioned in other comments :)

Comment: i cant put it in div our site is like blogger.

Answer (score 1):

try using `contextmenu` eventlistener:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
var ImageId = document.getElementById("image");
    if (ImageId.addEventListener) {
        ImageId.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
            alert("You've tried to open context menu"); //here you draw your own menu
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
    } else {
        ImageId.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function() {
            alert("You've tried to open context menu");
            window.event.returnValue = false;
        });
    }
})()
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="image" src="" />
</body>
</html>
```

> Make Custom ContextMenu

Check out this Tutorial on creating a custom context Menu :

> http://luke.breuer.com/tutorial/javascript-context-menu-tutorial.htm

Comment: i tried this one but i do not want disable complete right click i want to override context menu options.

Comment: how do i add our menu options??

Comment: Check out this tutorial : http://luke.breuer.com/tutorial/javascript-context-menu-tutorial.htm