# Browser Alert for Right-Click on Image

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know of a window alert script (browser message) that would make an alert appear when a user right-clicks on an image? The idea is to warn someone that the image is copyrighted, or that they need to cite the source if they want to use it, etc.  If such a script exists, is it possible to do this for just a specific image or images on the page, rather than a right-click anywhere on the page?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: There are a lot of answers for this question already on stackoverflow. Read about document.onmousedown for example.

Comment: This should work in all browsers: https://jsfiddle.net/a04m83k1/ (and can be adapted to block the right-click based on a class for instance)

Comment: Here's a partial dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686814/override-context-menu-for-image-right-click (my solution is better though)

Comment: The jsfiddle works.  Is there a way to use it to specify a certain image or images on a page, rather than *every* image on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a basic level:

```
<img onclick="window.alert('All copyrights reserved');" 
  oncontextmenu="window.alert('Image context menu is disabled');return false;"
  src="some.jpg"  
/>
```

Generally windows alerts are bad for usability. I suggest you look at another solution to protect your copyrights.

Also note that this does not prevent someone who is smart enough to save the image another way.  It is very easy to open the browser inspector & save the image from there or remove the onclick/oncontextmenu to allow access.

Comment: This only works on a left-click.  To download an image, you right-click.

Comment: Added the oncontextmenu to disable right-click

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.  But I might be doing something wrong.   (Also, just to clarify, I don't want to prevent someone from downloading an image.  I just want to remind them that if they do download it, they are responsible for providing proper credit when they use it.)

Comment: does it work for you on this page?  http://www.javascripter.net/faq/rightbu2.htm   .... try right-clicking on the little folder icon.  You can Ctrl+Shift+I in the browser to inspect the source code & see the example.

Comment: Yes, the right-click is disabled on that page for the little folder.  But what I'm looking for is to *not* disable the right-click, but to have an alert appear when someone does indeed right-click.  I do want the user to have the right-click options available.  I just want there to be an alert telling them that if they DO download an image, they have to credit it.  Maybe it's not possible to have both.

Comment: Then you have the same code to display the alert but return true instead of false.  Consider that not all screenreader+browers combinations will be compatible with an alert box.   You could instead display a text box over the image with copyright info.  Here is a custom dialog box example: https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/WD-wai-aria-practices-1.2-20180719/examples/dialog-modal/alertdialog.html